# default alert dialog buttons height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framework

is there any way by which we can chage default alertdialog buttons(Cancel and Save) height and width in framework of android..

i mean somwhere in path

frameworks/base/core/res/res

i am not looking for custom alertDialog.
i just need to reduce width of statandard alertdialog buttons...
is there any way??..from 2 days m pulling my hairs :(

I tried modifying frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml
but changes i made ain't working

below is alert_dialog.xml file code

```
<com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="9dip"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:paddingRight="1dip"
    android:majorWeight="0.65"
    android:minorWeight="0.9">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="54dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
            <com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark" />
        <!-- If the client uses a customTitle, it will be added here. -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dip"
            android:paddingBottom="12dip"
            android:paddingLeft="14dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/customPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+android:id/custom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="4dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:paddingRight="2dip"
            android:useLargestChild="true">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftSpacer"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightSpacer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to do this you have to create costume dialog

Comment: there must be some changes that i can made with default layout file..is there any??

Comment: sorry to correct your Nirav its custom dialog.

Comment: Consider using the 'Material Dialogs' library on GitHub: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Answer (score 3):

No need to create custom layout, try this:

create res/values/dimens.xml:

`<resources>`

```
<dimen name="alertdialog_button_width">150dp</dimen>
<dimen name="alertdialog_button_height">150dp</dimen>
```

`</resources>`

Then add in this code snippet:

```
private void setButtonSize(AlertDialog dialog) {
    Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.alertdialog_button_height);
    int width  = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.alertdialog_button_width);

    button.setHeight(height);
    button.setWidth(width);
}
```

If you're using a DialogFragment, then cast the `getDialog()` to `AlertDialog` and pass it into `setButtonSize`.
You can additionally specify a third parameter for passing in the button id (BUTTON_NEGATIVE, BUTTON_NEUTRAL, etc.)

Comment: Note that `setButtonSize()` must be called after `dialog.show()`. Also note: You can also use `button.setPadding()` to reduce the internal padding inside the button, which allows more text to fit in it, without clipping.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this create your own layout xml and pass in your Dialog.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);//put this layout here
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");
```

read this    http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

**update:-**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="showOk"
        android:text="Ok" 
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".5"/>
```

see in my app i am doing like this

```
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".5"
```

so you can set the button size like this..increase and reduce the size according to need.

Comment: actauly i need to change buttons(cancel and save) size for DatepickerDialog ..since datepickerDialog extends AlertDialog so i need to change layout for alertDialog only...

Comment: first read this.if you want to ,make change in buttons size you can set there sizes in your xml it self

Comment: vl try this...what does   android:scaleX means??

Answer (score 0):

It possible with custom dialogue box only.because we can't default ones.in custom dialogues you can have to size of alert dialogue and custom size.